# Order stuck on processing - how to set order status to complete manually

Tags: order-status

One order is still set to "processing" although the payment was captured and received by authorize.net. I did some research and learned that a shipment and an invoice must exist before an order can be set to "complete".

In my case the invoice was missing. I creatd an invoice manually in backend but when I hit the "capture" button I did get following error:

*`Credit Card: xxxx-1234 amount $10.89 capture - failed. Authorize.Net Transaction ID 1234567890. Gateway error: The transaction cannot be found.`*

This is odd because the payment went already through. So I even don't want to capture the payment again. But I also can't set the status to complete in backend.

What do you suggest in this case?

I could set the status to "complete" by running following queries - but I feel like its not the best way to get it fixed.

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state = 'completed', status = 'completed' WHERE increment_id IN (1234567);
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = 'completed' WHERE increment_id IN (1234567);
```

Thanks!